# Python3 Raspberry Pi (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'RPi') with code and error

Tags: python

```
enter code here
```

Hi, I am having this problem with my raspberry pi where I am trying to run a program but it does not recognize 'RP. I have installed RPi using pip install RPi.GPIO. Whenever I try "Sudo apt-get install python-RPI.gpio python3-RPI.gpio," it says the package is only available from another source. So I have the package installed but python3 can't seem to access it. Please help if you know how to solve this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
########################################################################
# Filename    : LightWater.py
# Description : Use LEDBar Graph(10 LED)
# auther      : www.freenove.com
# modification: 2019/12/28
########################################################################

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

ledPins = [11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 18, 22, 3, 5, 24]

buttonpin = 32

def setup():

    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)        # use PHYSICAL GPIO Numbering
    GPIO.setup(ledPins, GPIO.OUT)   # set all ledPins to OUTPUT mode
    GPIO.output(ledPins, GPIO.HIGH) # make all ledPins output HIGH level, turn off all led
    GPIO.setup(buttonpin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)


def loop():

    while True:

        for pin in ledPins:  # make led(on) move from left to right
            GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.LOW)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.HIGH)
        for pin in ledPins[::-1]:  # make led(on) move from right to left
            GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.LOW)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.HIGH)

def display():

    while True:

        if GPIO.input(buttonpin) == GPIO.LOW:
            loop()
        else:
            GPIO.output(ledPins, GPIO.HIGH)

def destroy():
    GPIO.cleanup()                     # Release all GPIO

if __name__ == '__main__':     # Program entrance
    print ('Program is starting...')
    setup()
    try:
        display()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:  # Press ctrl-c to end the program.
        destroy()
```

"import RPi.GPIO as GPIO ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'RPi'"

Comment: Which version of RPi.GPIO you instealed?

Comment: I'm not sure what library you mean. I just used pip install RPi.GPIO. Is there a way to check which library on the command line?

Comment: I think it is called cpython-37

Comment: You can try to upgrade it maybe it will help ```sudo pip install --upgrade RPi.GPIO```.

Comment: If not try to check your __init__.py .

Comment: My version of RPi.GPIO is GPIO - 0.7.0.dist

Comment: Actually, it is just GPIO - 0.7.0

Comment: Hi after rechecking my RPi.GPIO version for python3 is 1.5.1