# Python3 Raspberry Pi (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'RPi') with code and error and RPi.GPIO version

Tags: python

I am having this problem with my raspberry pi where I am trying to run a program but it does not recognize 'RP. I have installed RPi using pip install RPi.GPIO. Whenever I try "Sudo apt-get install python-RPI.gpio python3-RPI.gpio," it says the package is only available from another source. So I have the package installed but python3 can't seem to access it. My RPi.GPIO version for python3 is 1.5.1.
Please help if you know how to solve this

Comment: Try doing a 
"sudo apt-get update"
to update your Pi's repositories first and see if that helps.

Comment: This is the **3rd** time you have asked this exact question today (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66599005/python3-raspberry-pi-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-rpi and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66600793/python3-raspberry-pi-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-rpi-with-code-and). What gives?